# Error adding custom route to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've rewritten my question to be more accurate.  I have a bankaccounts controller / model.

I have the following method on my controller

```
def search
  #@ledgeritems = Ledgeritem.where("bankaccount_id = ? and transactiondate >= ? and transactiondate < ?", params[:bankaccount_id], params[:startdate], params[:enddate])
  @bankaccount = Bankaccount.find(params[:bankaccount_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :partial => "bankaccount/bankledger" }
  end
end
```

I've made two attempts to call this.

**Attempt 1**

Route for attempt 1

```
resources :bankaccounts do
    post "search"
end
```

This shows the following route when I do a rake

```
bankaccount_search POST   /bankaccounts/:bankaccount_id/search(.:format) bankaccounts#search
```

Javascript for calling attempt 1

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/bankaccounts/" + bank_account_id + "/search.js",
    data: $('#edit_bankaccount_' + bank_account_id).serialize(),
    success: function (result, status) {
        $('#bank_ledger_div').html(result);
    }
});
```

This calls the correct route on my controller, but the server sees it as a PUT instead of a POST and returns a 404.

**Attempt 2**

Route for attempt 2

```
resources :bankaccounts do
  collection do
    post "search"
  end
end
```

This shows the following route when I do a rake

```
search_bankaccounts POST   /bankaccounts/search(.:format)       bankaccounts#search
```

Javascript for calling attempt 2

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/bankaccounts/search.js",
    data: $('#edit_bankaccount_' + bank_account_id).serialize(),
    success: function (result, status) {
        $('#bank_ledger_div').html(result);
    }
});
```

This calls the update route but still showing as a PUT command.  In Firebug I see a 500 error with the following result

```
Couldn't find Bankaccount with id=search
```

Comment: I'm checking it with Firebug and I see it's a post being set to localhost:3000/bankaccounts/search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this error means you're making a GET request instead of a POST request.

For example:

GET /bankaccounts/search is assumed to be requesting the SHOW page for a bankaccount with ID = search

While

POST /bankaccounts/search would correctly hit your action.

**Edit:**

```
resources :bankaccounts do
  collection do
    post "search"
  end
end
```

Is correct as well. Now I'm noticing that you are doing this to get your data:

```
data: $('#edit_bankaccount_' + bank_account_id).serialize()
```

that form likely has a hidden field in it, put there by rails, with name='_method' and value='PUT'. That is what is convincing rails that your POST is really a PUT. You'll need to remove that from the serialized data in order to correctly post the form.

Comment: I updated my question to show the ajax I'm using.  I can see in Firebug it's a post request and it's going to localhost:3000/bankaccounts/search

Comment: I've rewritten my question to better show what I'm doing and seeing.

Comment: That was it, that hidden put value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `/search` url to be used without specifying an id, you should declare it as a `collection` action :

```
resources :bankaccounts do
  collection do
    post "search"
  end
end
```

You can check the routes defined in your app with the `rake routes` command, to ensure that you defined what you meant.

Comment: I updated the routes as you showed, and in my on my rake I see
search_bankaccounts POST   /bankaccounts/search(.:format)       bankaccounts#search
but I still get the error

Comment: The log of the server might help you to understand what is happening (which controller and action are called, with what params).

Comment: I've rewritten my question to better show what I'm doing and seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is expecting the format

```
/bankaccounts/:bankaccount_id/search
```

Is the error coming from this method?  Could /bankaccounts/search be matching another route?

Comment: I rewrote my question to better show what I'm doing and seeing.